# matplotlib.pyplotでプロットができません

Tags: python

下記のようにデータセットをjupyter notebookでプロットしたいんですができません
なぜでしょうか？

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import mglearn
from IPython.display import display


#データセットをプロット
mglearn.discrete_scatter(X[:, 0], X[:, 1], y)
plt.legend(["Class 0", "Class 1"], loc=4)
plt.xlabel("First feeature")
plt.ylabel("Second feature")
print("X.shape: {}".format(X.shape))

Out[11]: X.shape: (26, 2)

X, y = mglearn.datasets.make_wave(n_samples=40)
plt.plot(X, y, 'o')
plt.ylim(-3, 3)
plt.xlabel("Feature")
plt.ylabel("Target")

Out[14]: <matplotlib.text.Text at 0x11d29a080>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

コードの先頭行でも他のセルでも構いませんので

```
%matplotlib inline
```

を実行してください

Comment: できました。有難うございます。